# Cleveref mislabels figures when using \ContinuedFloat

Tags: cross-referencing, subfloats, cleveref

When using subfloats over multiple pages I have used `\ContinuedFloat` to carry on the figure environment which also preserves the numbering. However, when I try to reference the whole figure, `cleveref` does not get the label correct.

There are numerous answers available for misnumbering but not mislabeling.

Have I put the `\label` in the wrong place?

MWE as follows with all the packages I'm using:

```
\documentclass[12pt,demo]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[capitalise]{cleveref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{caption}


\begin{document}

\section{Section Title}
\Cref{fig:First} and \cref{fig:Second} can be seen in \cref{fig:Both}.


\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[Caption for the first image]{
\includegraphics[width=.4\columnwidth]{Img1}%
\label{fig:First}%
}
\phantomcaption
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\ContinuedFloat
\centering
\subfloat[Caption for the second image]{
\includegraphics[width=.4\columnwidth]{Img2}%
\label{fig:Second}%
}
\caption{Main Caption}%
\label{fig:Both}%
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can offer a solution that uses the [subcaption](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package and its `subfigure` environment instead of the `subfig` package and its `\subfloat` macro. I suggest making this change because the `\ContinuedFloat` macro (which is provided by the `caption` package, which is loaded automatically by the `subcaption` package) seems to interact in an unfortunate way with the `subfig` package's macros, ending up confusing `cleveref`. Possibly because the `subcaption` and `caption` packages were created by the same author, labeling does *not* get messed up if you employ `\ContinuedFloat` along with `subfigure` environments.

The syntax for creating subfigures needs to be adjusted a bit if you use the macros of the `subcaption` package. However, I trust the adjustments won't be too burdensome.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,demo]{elsarticle}
%% commented out the following packages as they aren't needed for the MWE
%\usepackage{enumerate}
%\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{mathtools}
%\usepackage{tabu}
%\usepackage{multirow}
%\usepackage{textcomp}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{comment}
%\usepackage[section]{placeins}
%\usepackage{float}

%%%\usepackage{subfig} do not use load this package

\usepackage{subcaption} %%% instead, load the 'subcaption' package
     %%% 'subcaption' loads 'caption', which provides the macro \ContinuedFloat

\usepackage[capitalise,noabbrev]{cleveref} %%% load 'cleveref' last

\begin{document}

\section{Section Title}

\Cref{fig:First,fig:Second} can be seen in \cref{fig:Both}.

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.4\columnwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Img1}%
\caption{Caption for the first image}
\label{fig:First}%
\end{subfigure}
%%% \phantomcaption %% no need for this statement
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\ContinuedFloat
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.4\columnwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Img2}%
\caption{Caption for the second image}
\label{fig:Second}%
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Main Caption}%
\label{fig:Both}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. Does the `subcaption` package incorporate all of the functionality of the `subfigure` and `subfig` packages then?

Comment: @LearningLaTeX - the `subfigure` package is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore. I guess one can say that the `subcaption` package can do everything the `subfig` package does. However, `subcaption` isn't compatible with the document class `revtex4-1`. Thus, for the users of that document class, `subfig` is the only practical choice. There may also be cases of incompatibility between `subcaption` and other LaTeX packages, though they're becoming less common.